# Native Instruments Maschine Mikro and Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, alsa

After searching a solution wherever I could, I'm resigned to ask it myself.
I'm the owner of a Maschine Mikro MKII from Native Instruments and, some months ago, I switched to Ubuntu Gnome (under 15.10 right now), preventing me to use my Maschine controller.
Two weeks ago I began seeking a solution to make it work.
First, when plugging it, it starts, but does not go past the bright 'welcome' screen, also when doing `cat /proc/asound/seq/clients` it does not show up the Maschine Controller.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/seq/clients 
Client info
  cur  clients : 2
  peak clients : 2
  max  clients : 192

Client   0 : "System" [Kernel]
  Port   0 : "Timer" (Rwe-)
  Port   1 : "Announce" (R-e-)
Client  14 : "Midi Through" [Kernel]
  Port   0 : "Midi Through Port-0" (RWe-)
```

Tried to compile and install alsa-lib, alsa-oss, alsa-utils and alsa-firmware from source, big mistake, messed up my audio. Currently repairing it.

The [alsa-project wiki](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-usb-caiaq) page that Native Instruments is redirecting user to seems a good source, but I think it is way outdated as it mentioning the old 'alsa-driver'.

So, if you managed to make your Maschine controller works, how did you achieved it ?

Thanks.
Regards, PLD.

Comment: ALSA's [NI page](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Native_Instruments) says "unknown".

Comment: ohh boy , it would be so awesome if we could use Maschine an something like this:
https://elementary.io and forget all that OS X Windows crap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old post, but I just tried some things and this is what I got so far:

I noticed a few buttons actually respond already, that means that some driver is loaded. (`Browse` acts like right-mouse click )

```
$ ls-usb
...
Bus 001 Device 113: ID 17cc:0808 Native Instruments Maschine Controller

$ usb-devices 
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=113 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=17cc ProdID=0808 Rev=00.0d
S:  Manufacturer=Native Instruments
S:  Product=Maschine Controller
S:  SerialNumber=SN-12345678     
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=280mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 1 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-caiaq
```

Notice `Driver=snd-usb-caiaq`. 
I didnt install anything, so that must be default stuff in Ubuntu 16.04, and actually, NI sneaked in some kernelmodules:
https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SND_USB_CAIAQ.html :)

To find which device is used, I used the number found with `ls-usb`

```
$ grep  0808 /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idProduct
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/idProduct:0808
$ cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/
$ cat product
Maschine Controller
```

After `modprobe usbmon` the device raw data can be viewed using

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1t
```

Comment: Interesting! Since, people tried a bit to make it work: https://github.com/wrl/maschine.rs
But I think, the CAIAQ modules thing was made mainly for the NI soundcards.